# How do I go about removing the gap from the my fixed bottom navbar

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change the way my menu looks by moving the links onto the same line as the social media icons and home button.

The links are inside a div under the main navbar class (streetworn-demos), the social media icons and homepage are floated to their respected sides in their own divs too. I've tried changing the width of the navbar class thinking it would just slot in, but it just changed the positioning of the links.

How do I make it so that the links and the 
icons for each social media are on the same line, centered?

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,700);

*,
*:after,
*:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}

body {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Raleway', Arial, sans-serif;
}

a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 700;
  outline: none;
}


/* Link Colours */

.fade {
  background: #333;
}

.fade a {
  color: #fff;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
  color: #333;
}

.social {
  float: left;
  clear: none;
}

#social {
  padding: 5px;
}


/* Buttons */

.Streetworn-demos {
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #ff9966;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}

.Streetworn-demos a {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0.5em 0.75em;
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: 'Raleway', cursive;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.about h3 {
  font-family: 'Satisfy', cursive;
  font-size: 32px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px 25px 25px 5px;
  background-color: #ff9966;
}

.about p {
  font-family: 'Raleway', cursive;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: auto;
}

.login {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ff9966;
}

#home {
  padding: 5px;
}

.homepage {
  float: right;
  clear: none;
}

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
main,
nav,
section,
summary {
  display: block;
}

audio,
canvas,
video {
  display: inline-block;
}

audio:not([controls]) {
  display: none;
  height: 0;
}

[hidden] {
  display: none;
}

html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

a:focus {
  outline: thin dotted;
}

a:active,
a:hover {
  outline: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0.67em 0;
}

abbr[title] {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}

b,
strong {
  font-weight: bold;
}

dfn {
  font-style: italic;
}

hr {
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 0;
}

mark {
  background: #ff0;
  color: #000;
}

code,
kbd,
pre,
samp {
  font-family: monospace, serif;
  font-size: 1em;
}

pre {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

q {
  quotes: "\201C" "\201D" "\2018" "\2019";
}

small {
  font-size: 80%;
}

sub,
sup {
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

sup {
  top: -0.5em;
}

sub {
  bottom: -0.25em;
}

img {
  border: 0;
}

svg:not(:root) {
  overflow: hidden;
}

figure {
  margin: 0;
}

fieldset {
  border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  margin: 0 2px;
  padding: 0.35em 0.625em 0.75em;
}

legend {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

button,
input,
select,
textarea {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

button,
input {
  line-height: normal;
}

button,
select {
  text-transform: none;
}

button,
html input[type="button"],
input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"] {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button[disabled],
html input[disabled] {
  cursor: default;
}

input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
}

input[type="search"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

textarea {
  overflow: auto;
  vertical-align: top;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="login">
  <a class="loginlink" href="#">Login / Signup</a>
</div>

<nav class="Streetworn-demos">
  <div class="navbar">
    <a class="brands" href="#">PALACE</a>
    <a class="brands" href="#">GOLFWANG</a>
    <a class="brands" href="#">SUPREME</a>
    <a class="brands" href="#">BILLIONAIRE'S BOYS CLUB</a>
    <a class="brands" href="#">STUSSY</a>
    <a class="brands" href="#">ANTISOCIAL SOCIAL CLUB</a>
  </div>
  <div class="homepage">
    <a class="home" href="index.html"><img id="home" alt="Return to the landing page" src="https://image.ibb.co/fnApE7/home2.png" style="height: 36px; width: 36px" onmouseover="this.src='https://image.ibb.co/bwSEgn/homeicon.png'" onmouseout="this.src='https://image.ibb.co/fnApE7/home2.png'"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="social">
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/"><img id="social" alt="Follow Streetworn on Facebook!" src="https://image.ibb.co/ftLBSS/fb2.png" style="height: 36px; width: 36px" onmouseover="this.src='https://image.ibb.co/ktUS1n/fbicon.png'" onmouseout="this.src='https://image.ibb.co/ftLBSS/fb2.png'"></a>
    <a href="http://www.instagram.com/"><img id="social" alt="Follow Streetworn on Instagram!" src="https://image.ibb.co/fDPugn/ig2.png" style="height: 36px; width: 36px" onmouseover="this.src='https://image.ibb.co/e5o9E7/igicon.png'" onmouseout="this.src='https://image.ibb.co/fDPugn/ig2.png'"></a>
    <a href="http://www.twitter.com/"><img id="social" alt="Follow Streetworn on Twitter!" src="https://image.ibb.co/cK5Zgn/twitter2.png" style="height: 36px; width: 36px" onmouseover="this.src='https://image.ibb.co/eGbJ7S/twittericon.png'" onmouseout="this.src='https://image.ibb.co/cK5Zgn/twitter2.png'"></a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Any help would be massively appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using floats, the easiest thing to do would be to just reorder the homepage and social divs to come before the navbar div, so that they float out of the way first, and the navbar will occupy the space between them:

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,700);
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}

body {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Raleway', Arial, sans-serif;
}

a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 700;
  outline: none;
}


/* Link Colours */

.fade {
  background: #333;
}

.fade a {
  color: #fff;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
  color: #333;
}

.social {
  float: left;
  clear: none;
}

#social {
  padding: 5px;
}


/* Buttons */

.Streetworn-demos {
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #ff9966;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}

.Streetworn-demos a {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0.5em 0.75em;
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: 'Raleway', cursive;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.about h3 {
  font-family: 'Satisfy', cursive;
  font-size: 32px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px 25px 25px 5px;
  background-color: #ff9966;
}

.about p {
  font-family: 'Raleway', cursive;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: auto;
}

.login {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ff9966;
}

#home {
  padding: 5px;
}

.homepage {
  float: right;
  clear: none;
}

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
main,
nav,
section,
summary {
  display: block;
}

audio,
canvas,
video {
  display: inline-block;
}

audio:not([controls]) {
  display: none;
  height: 0;
}

[hidden] {
  display: none;
}

html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

a:focus {
  outline: thin dotted;
}

a:active,
a:hover {
  outline: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0.67em 0;
}

abbr[title] {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}

b,
strong {
  font-weight: bold;
}

dfn {
  font-style: italic;
}

hr {
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 0;
}

mark {
  background: #ff0;
  color: #000;
}

code,
kbd,
pre,
samp {
  font-family: monospace, serif;
  font-size: 1em;
}

pre {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

q {
  quotes: "\201C" "\201D" "\2018" "\2019";
}

small {
  font-size: 80%;
}

sub,
sup {
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

sup {
  top: -0.5em;
}

sub {
  bottom: -0.25em;
}

img {
  border: 0;
}

svg:not(:root) {
  overflow: hidden;
}

figure {
  margin: 0;
}

fieldset {
  border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  margin: 0 2px;
  padding: 0.35em 0.625em 0.75em;
}

legend {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

button,
input,
select,
textarea {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

button,
input {
  line-height: normal;
}

button,
select {
  text-transform: none;
}

button,
html input[type="button"],
input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"] {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button[disabled],
html input[disabled] {
  cursor: default;
}

input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
}

input[type="search"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

textarea {
  overflow: auto;
  vertical-align: top;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="login">
  <a class="loginlink" href="#">Login / Signup</a>
</div>

<nav class="Streetworn-demos">
  <div class="homepage">
    <a class="home" href="index.html"><img id="home" alt="Return to the landing page" src="https://image.ibb.co/fnApE7/home2.png" style="height: 36px; width: 36px" onmouseover="this.src='https://image.ibb.co/bwSEgn/homeicon.png'" onmouseout="this.src='https://image.ibb.co/fnApE7/home2.png'"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="social">
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/"><img id="social" alt="Follow Streetworn on Facebook!" src="https://image.ibb.co/ftLBSS/fb2.png" style="height: 36px; width: 36px" onmouseover="this.src='https://image.ibb.co/ktUS1n/fbicon.png'" onmouseout="this.src='https://image.ibb.co/ftLBSS/fb2.png'"></a>
    <a href="http://www.instagram.com/"><img id="social" alt="Follow Streetworn on Instagram!" src="https://image.ibb.co/fDPugn/ig2.png" style="height: 36px; width: 36px" onmouseover="this.src='https://image.ibb.co/e5o9E7/igicon.png'" onmouseout="this.src='https://image.ibb.co/fDPugn/ig2.png'"></a>
    <a href="http://www.twitter.com/"><img id="social" alt="Follow Streetworn on Twitter!" src="https://image.ibb.co/cK5Zgn/twitter2.png" style="height: 36px; width: 36px" onmouseover="this.src='https://image.ibb.co/eGbJ7S/twittericon.png'" onmouseout="this.src='https://image.ibb.co/cK5Zgn/twitter2.png'"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar">
    <a class="brands" href="#">PALACE</a>
    <a class="brands" href="#">GOLFWANG</a>
    <a class="brands" href="#">SUPREME</a>
    <a class="brands" href="#">BILLIONAIRE'S BOYS CLUB</a>
    <a class="brands" href="#">STUSSY</a>
    <a class="brands" href="#">ANTISOCIAL SOCIAL CLUB</a>
  </div>

</nav>
```

*As a side note, remember that all your IDs **must** be unique*

Comment: Thanks man! It's crazy how you managed to solve something I've been racking my brain about for the past 3 hours within a minute lol.